# How to convert a pandas dataframe into one dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe `X`. I want to convert it into 1D array with only 5 elements.  One way of doing it is converting the inner arrays to lists. How can I do that?

```
      0     1   2          3           4           5
0   1622    95  1717   85.278544    1138.964373 1053.685830
1   62     328  390    75.613900    722.588235  646.974336
2   102    708  810    75.613900    800.916667  725.302767
3   102    862  964    75.613900    725.870370  650.256471
4   129    1380 1509   75.613900    783.711111  708.097211
```

`val = X.values` will give a numpy array. I want to convert the inner elements of the array to list. How can I do that?
I tried this but failed

```
M = val.values.tolist()
A = np.array(M,dtype=list)
N = np.array(M,dtype=object)
```

Comment: Are you after `X.stack()`?

Comment: Nope. I want a one dimensional array with only 5 elements not series. See @Divakar's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one approach to have each row as one list to give us a `1D` array of lists -

```
In [231]: df
Out[231]: 
      0     1     2          3            4            5
0  1622    95  1717  85.278544  1138.964373  1053.685830
1    62   328   390  75.613900   722.588235   646.974336
2   102   708   810  75.613900   800.916667   725.302767
3   102   862   964  75.613900   725.870370   650.256471
4   129  1380  1509  75.613900   783.711111   708.097211

In [232]: out = np.empty(df.shape[0], dtype=object)

In [233]: out[:] = df.values.tolist()

In [234]: out
Out[234]: 
array([list([1622.0, 95.0, 1717.0, 85.278544, 1138.964373, 1053.6858300000001]),
       list([62.0, 328.0, 390.0, 75.6139, 722.5882349999999, 646.974336]),
       list([102.0, 708.0, 810.0, 75.6139, 800.916667, 725.302767]),
       list([102.0, 862.0, 964.0, 75.6139, 725.87037, 650.256471]),
       list([129.0, 1380.0, 1509.0, 75.6139, 783.7111110000001, 708.097211])], dtype=object)

In [235]: out.shape
Out[235]: (5,)

In [236]: out.ndim
Out[236]: 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Divakar this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `df.as_matrix()` and then join rows?

### EDIT:

Example:

```
L=[]
for m in df.as_matrix().tolist():
    L += m
```

Comment: I wanted a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

If it has only one column, you can try this

```
op_col = []
for i in df_name['Column_name']:
    op_col.append(i)
print(op_col)
```